# Dell Latitude E6540 Windows 10 Won't allow latest intel graphics driver to install

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, dell-latitude, display-driver

Below is the error message at the end of the log. I'm using dell support assist on the Dell Latitude e6540 running Windows 10 22H2 and trying to install the Intel HD iris 4600 Graphics driver - which it does - But the core security blocks it from working. That is with the 2017 version that the intel driver asisstant software installs automatically. The website has a 2019 version and when I try to manually install it is when the error below occurs.

> Removed C:\ProgramData\Dell\drivers\c0e2ec64-43dd-4d68-b1a6->e40087160527\DisplayAudio\8.20\IntcDAud.inf
> Removed C:\ProgramData\Dell\drivers\c0e2ec64-43dd-4d68-b1a6-e40087160527\Graphics\ki130515.inf
> Checking 4 part DID's
> 4ID check OK
>
> - GFX HW not found; disabling HDMI driver install
>   Removed INF = C:\ProgramData\Dell\drivers\c0e2ec64-43dd-4d68-b1a6->e40087160527\DisplayAudio\6.16\IntcDAud.inf
>   !   Didn't find any INF's that match active hardware
>   IIF will NOT initiate reboot
>   Exit code = 0xA005
>   ResultCode = 40965
>   <<< 2/21/2023 15:53:22:410
>
> [Tue Feb 21 15:53:22 2023]
> --- End of Vendor Software Log ---
>
> [Tue Feb 21 15:53:22 2023] Vendor Software Return Code: 5
> [Tue Feb 21 15:53:22 2023] logo.png
> [Tue Feb 21 15:53:22 2023] Name of Exit Code: DEP_HARD_ERROR
> [Tue Feb 21 15:53:22 2023] Exit Code set to: 4 (0x4)
> [Tue Feb 21 15:53:22 2023] Result: FAILURE
> [Tue Feb 21 15:53:30 2023] Open file: C:\ProgramData\Dell\UpdatePackage\Log\Intel-HD-Graphics->4000-5000-500-P500-series-Driver_WWW9Y_WIN_20.19.15.5063_A10_01.txt

Comment: Can you fully uninstall the current Intel Driver (takes you back to VGA), restart and then install the newest driver?  (2) Are BIOS and all other drivers up to date?  (3) Contact Dell Suppot.

Comment: Agreed with @John, we're not supposed to do Dell's job ;-) If nothing works, download SDI Tools [here](https://sdi-tool.org/) - make a system restauration point!

Comment: So are you able to install the driver if you disable Core Isolation? Older drivers like the one your attempting to install might not be compatible. I would be shocked if the either driver actually supports 22H2

Comment: @Ramhound No I have tried turning all of those settings off in UEFI but it says the same thing with all files I try to use to install. I believe the attempt I got this error from was a package I copied from an old laptop, but when I try using Dell or Intel updater softwares (downloaded from the official site) it still says the kernel couldn't blah blah. Just frustrating because now the hdmi and vga ports don't work and no miracast either but all used to work

Comment: Unless you provide exactly what you receive I have nothing else I can provide.  Please be more specific by editing your question. The thing about drivers for the Intel HD iris 4600 I know Intel discontinued support it back in 2019 which is the reason your unlikely to get it working with Core Isolation on 22H2

Comment: Core Isolation is turned off within Windows not UEFI